# Speeglm $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, glm, speedglm

I am trying to execute the following code of a binary logit:

```
mylogit <- speedglm(dependent_variable ~ InterestRate, data = my_data, family = "binomial")
```

But I get the following error:

```
> mylogit <- speedglm(dependent_variable ~ InterestRate, data = my_data, family = "binomial")
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Here are the heads of the variables:

```
> head(my_data$dependent_variable)
[1] 0 1 1 1 1 1
> head(my_data$InterestRate)
[1] "0.165500" "0.165500" "0.165500" "0.165500" "0.165500" "0.165500"
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT:

Changing

```
family = "binomial"
```

to

```
family=binomial('logit')
```

seems to make it work

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: library("speedglm")

Comment: First step: Fix the data type of `my_data$InterestRate`. It is currently a character variable but should apparently be numeric.

Comment: @Roland how do I do that? by my_data$InterestRate <- as.numeric(as.character(my_data$InterestRate))?

Comment: with `as.numeric()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Changing

```
family = "binomial"
```

to

```
family=binomial('logit')
```

seems to make it work